# how to set clipPath for View in react native like this design?

Tags: responsive-design, react-native, clip-path, react-native-stylesheet

[I want to implement such a plan in React Native, but I could not help it in any way.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ95l.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried? Please mention your attempts too.

Comment: I have not thought of anything at all for this matter